# R table, 2 factor variables, cannot generate column percentages

Tags: r

I have two factor variables that I want to put in a table/crosstab to get frequencies across the categories. I want to express these frequencies as column percentages, i.e., calculated *only* on the counts for each column (each column should have a 100% percent total).

Whenever I execute my script with `prop.table(tab1, 2)`, R returns what appears to be column percentages where each category is a proportion of the entire sample, not exclusively the column frequencies (I should also note that the data are weighted, although I can replicate the problem without the weights).

I have searched painfully to find a solution, and nothing thus far has worked. I have tried converting the table to a matrix and a data frame, but this hasn't helped. I tried different packages, `xtabs()` and other functions to now avail.

Here's the relevant code:

```
# Raw data import | will make copy for editing.

rawdata = read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
data = rawdata

# Install Rcmdr for wtd.table() function

install.packages("Rcmdr")
library(Rcmdr)

# Create table

tab1 <- wtd.table(data$occ, data$degree, weights = data$PERWT)
tab1

prop.table(tab1, 2)
prop.table(tab1, 2)*100
```

For the weighted count, the table generates no problem (for actual data, there are 15 degree categories and 26 job categories):

```
        Deg1    Deg2    Deg3    Deg4    Deg5    
Job1    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    
Job2    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    
Job3    3000    3000    3000    3000    3000    
Job4    4000    4000    4000    4000    4000   
Job5    5000    5000    5000    5000    5000
```

When I run `prop.table(tab1, 2)`, I expect something like this:

```
        Deg1    Deg2    Deg3    Deg4    Deg5    
Job1    0.07    0.07    0.07    0.07    0.07 
Job2    0.13    0.13    0.13    0.13    0.13  
Job3    0.20    0.20    0.20    0.20    0.20 
Job4    0.27    0.27    0.27    0.27    0.27 
Job5    0.33    0.33    0.33    0.33    0.33
```

What I actually get, however, are bizarre numbers that appear to be based on the entire sample, not just the column, e.g.:

```
        Deg1           
Job1    5.088906e-03
Job2    1.94034e-02
Job3    6.236119e-03
Job4    4.495131e-02
Job5    1.315560e-01
```

This pattern repeats across all 15 degree and all 26 job categories. Running `prop.table(tab1, 2)*100` has no effect: the values remain exactly the same, unaffected by the multiplication.

I am very much at a loss here, and as a new R user, I'm sure I'm making some sort of easy mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `prop.table` with `apply`:

```
apply(tab, 2, prop.table)
```

The second argument `2` specifies that we are applying `prop.table` to each *column* of the matrix/dataframe.

**Output:**

```
           Deg1       Deg2       Deg3       Deg4       Deg5
Job1 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667
Job2 0.13333333 0.13333333 0.13333333 0.13333333 0.13333333
Job3 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000
Job4 0.26666667 0.26666667 0.26666667 0.26666667 0.26666667
Job5 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333
```

**Data:**

```
tab <- structure(c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 1000L, 2000L, 
3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 1000L, 
2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L
), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Job1", "Job2", "Job3", 
"Job4", "Job5"), c("Deg1", "Deg2", "Deg3", "Deg4", "Deg5")))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So, this worked on the non-weighted table perfectly, but with the weighted table, I cannot seem to replicate it. Is there a way to add weights within the apply() function?

Comment: @pomoneomarx I'm not sure what you meant by weighted vs non-weighted. You have only posted one input table in your question. What are the weights?

Comment: I figured it out -- thanks so much for your solution!